# Using a Zonal Network Endpoint Group (NEG) with HTTPS Load Balancer

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-http-load-balancer, google-cloud-network-load-balancer

When creating a Network Endpoint Group I need to specify network endpoint(s). For these, I can select my VM instance and specify the Primary (Internal) IP address.

I can then select this NEG as the backend of a Global HTTPS Load Balancer.

How is it possible for a globally distributed load balancer to forward traffic to a VM that does not have an external IP?

If I create an internal load balancer, the load balancer is deployed to a subnet within the same VPC, so it has line of sight to my instance, but the Global HTTPS load balancer is not in my VPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using zonal NEG you can go for internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing which is using internal Ip address as Primary address.There are two types of Zonal NEG:GCE_VM_IP and GCE_VM_IP_PORT zonal NEGs.
As you are using only Ip address ,the internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing is best choice
please refer:https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/zonal-neg-concepts